# Resizing Background image according to container Div

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a background image like image.jpg. I want to resize this image according to any div which is using it.

How can i do this in jquery or any other way.

Comment: you could use `background-size: 100% 100%;` in your css. if you only want it to fit in same aspect ratio in the `width` then `background-size: 100%;`

Comment: you could also use [`background-size:contain`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) for keeping the aspect ratio (this is css3 btw)

Comment: http://chuvash.eu/2011/09/28/resize-image-with-jquery-to-fit-the-div/

Answer (score 0):

There's many different ways to do this. The best in terms of execution speed is to use CSS, but jQuery can accomplish anything CSS can using the `$().css()` method.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Td68R/) with four five different methods, from just putting the image in, to stretching in css and jQuery. The code is below:

```
<style>
div
{
    background-image : url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6f/Les_Halles_%28metro_de_Paris%29_-_Entree.jpg/800px-Les_Halles_%28metro_de_Paris%29_-_Entree.jpg");

    height : 200px;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-repeat : no-repeat;
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
}

#one
{
    background-size:contain;
}

#two
{
    background-size: 100%;
}

#three
{
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}



</style>

<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="four"></div>
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
<div id="d"></div>

<script>
    $("#a").css("background-size","contain") //fits in aspect ratio
    $("#b").css("background-size","100%") //constrained by width
    $("#c").css("background-size","100% 100%") //stretch to fill
    $("#d").css("background-size","auto 100%") //constrained by height
</script>
```

Hope this sheds some light on the problem.

There's some good references available on CSS, if you want to explore the properties and see what else can be done.

Comment: `-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='images/someimage.png',sizingMethod='scale')";` For IE8+ (might work in earlier versions, but not sure)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532920(v=vs.85).aspx For Documentation on that particular MS hack.